# Background image not responsive & fully shown

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with responsiveness and appearance of my background image.

```css
#about {
  background-image: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/suxzj8.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.about-text {
  font-family: "montserrat-regular", sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="about">
    <br><br>
    <div class="about-text">
      <p>We are , an integrated communications partner delivering advertising, creative and BTL solutions. We provide not just solutions but provide them in a way that is crisp, clean and simple in order to attract the consumers’ attention and drive home the message at the same time. We also believe in integrated communications where your brand is in sync with your marketing. We create<span span style=font-weight:bold;color:black><font size=4> advertising designs, provide creative, BTL and print solutions</font></span>. We're here to make your business stand out from the crowd.<br><br>
      We are a group of professionals having worked in various organisations in different positions. We have seen the advertising world in and out. Our team has all the potential to create advertising campaigns that work well in the market.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/qpoWRY)

Can you please rectify me where I went wrong.

Comment: What's the issue with it?

Comment: background image is not showing fully and also it is not responsive

Comment: It's because you put it on your section rather than on your body, if you want it to cover the whole page, either make the section cover the whole page or  put the background on the body

Answer (score 0):

Your #about element is not as tall as the body / html.

Simply apply your CSS declaration to `body` for instance:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/suxzj8.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.about-text {
  font-family: "montserrat-regular", sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id=about>
  <br><br>
  <div class="about-text">
    <p>We are , an integrated communications partner delivering advertising, creative and BTL solutions. We provide not just solutions but provide them in a way that is crisp, clean and simple in order to attract the consumers’ attention and drive home the
      message at the same time. We also believe in integrated communications where your brand is in sync with your marketing. We create<span span style=font-weight:bold;color:black><font size=4> advertising designs, provide creative, BTL and print solutions</font></span>.
      We're here to make your business stand out from the crowd.<br><br> We are a group of professionals having worked in various organisations in different positions. We have seen the advertising world in and out. Our team has all the potential to create
      advertising campaigns that work well in the market.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have Different sections in single webpage so I make it as `section`

Comment: Then if you section is not tall enough to show the whole image, how can the image be displayed in full?

Comment: He could use `background-size: contain;`

Comment: @Sébastien I have different section's like about us, portfolio, services. For each section I have to use different background images and it has to be displayed fully

Comment: You would have to know the height of each background image and set each section's CSS `min-height` property accordingly, or maybe use JavaScript to accomplish this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `#about` to have this background, and you want the whole image showing, you can try using `background-size: contain;`

```
#about {
background-image:url(http://i65.tinypic.com/suxzj8.jpg) ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: contain;
min-height: 500px;
}
.about-text {
font-family:"montserrat-regular",sans-serif;
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
margin-left:25%;
margin-right:20%;
color:black; 
}
```

On the responsive side of it, I'd probably remove that image when the resolution is small enough.  You could try something like below.

```
#about {
background-image: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/suxzj8.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
min-height: 500px;
}
.aboutUs {
display: none;
}

.about-text {
font-family: "montserrat-regular", sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
text-justify: inter-word;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 20%;
color: black;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
#about{
background-image: none;
}
.aboutUs {
display: block;
background-color: #387438;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
}
}
```

Then your html would be as below

```
<section id="about">
<br><br>
        <div class="about-text">
          <h1 class="aboutUs">about us</h1>
        <p>We are , an integrated communications partner delivering advertising, creative and BTL solutions. We provide not just solutions but provide them in a way that is crisp, clean and simple in order to attract the consumers’ attention and drive home the message at the same time. We also believe in integrated communications where your brand is in sync with your marketing. We create<span span style=font-weight:bold;color:black><font size=4> advertising designs, provide creative, BTL and print solutions</font></span>. We're here to make your business stand out from the crowd.<br><br>
        We are a group of professionals having worked in various organisations in different positions. We have seen the advertising world in and out. Our team has all the potential to create advertising campaigns that work well in the market.</p>
        </div>
 </section>
```

In my example if the res is below 768px it'll remove the background image and show about us with a generic style. You can of course change this to your needs. You should also consider removing the `br` tags and adding some `padding` or `margins` in instead. I've also set the `min-height:500px` which you can also change to suit your needs. Hope this helps.

[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/sconner87/pen/ypKORb)

Comment: when we resize the screen with the help of above code it can be  text cross the image

Comment: Yeah, ideally you'd write a media query to say if the screen size is less than a certain size, you'd probably not show that image as the quality wouldn't be great.

Comment: @noonecancatch I've updated my answer with some responsive changes for you to look at.  Let me know if this is any good for you.

Answer (score -2):

just change the   "background-size: cover;"
 to

```
#about{
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: when does it break ? i have just tried it on codepen and its working fine